# Check if there exist a row in 2D array of integers that is the sum of two other rows of the same array

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how can I code a program that returns true if there exist a row in a 2D array which is the sum of two other rows.

example of what my program should do:

if the 2D array is:

2  4  2  3

3  2  6  1

5  6  8  4

9  7  3  7

my code should return true because row[2] (3rd row) is the sum of row[0] (1st row) and row[1] (2nd row)

In my code, I search in the first column of my 2D array to find the location of a value that is the sum of two other values from different rows, but cannot figure out what to do after that.

```
    boolean someRowIsSumOfTwoOthers(int n, int [][] A){ 
        int i, j, k;
        boolean isTotal = false;
        for( i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
                if (i != j){        
                    for( k = 0; k < n; k++){
                       if ( (i != k) && (j != k) )  
                            if( A[i][0] == A[j][0] + A[k][0] )
                                isTotal = true;
                                 //once isTotal true, I need to increment column to check if isTotal still true for the rest of that same row
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( (i == n) && isTotal )
                return true;            
        }

        return false;                   
    }
```

Comment: I would definitely break this down into parts. First sum up all the rows in the array and put into another array(of size rows of course)? and then from there go through that and check.

Comment: Do you want to compares the total sums or each digit-sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you the desired answer

```
boolean someRowIsSumOfTwoOthers(int n, int [][] A){ 
    int i, j=0;
    int []rowSums=new int[n];
    boolean isTotal = false;
    //This part cut the code into one deminsion
    //Makes it eaiser to work with
    for(int[] b:A)
    {
        for(i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        {
            rowSums[j]+=b[i];
        }
        //useing j as a row incrimenter
        j++;
    }
    //for the value of one row
    int rowVal;
    //for the value of the other two
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        rowVal=rowSums[x];
        //nested forloop to test any of the other rows combinations
        for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
        {
            //check to keep row values from repeating
            if(y==x)
                y++;
            for(int z=0;z<n;z++)
            {
                //check to keep row values from repeating
                while(z==y || z==x)
                    z++;
                if(z>=n)
                    break;
                if(rowVal==rowSums[z]+rowSums[y])
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your unfamiliar with the for each loop i can upload the code without it. i just use it as a quick for loop

Answer (score 1):

For clarity I feel it'd be worth splitting the problem into two parts:

```
boolean rowIsSumOfTwoOthers(int[][] table) {
    int[] sums = sumOfRows(table);
    return oneIsSumOfTwoOthers(sums);
}
```

Each of these is relatively simple using Java 8 streams:

```
private int[] sumOfRows(int[][] table) {
    return IntStream.range(0, table.length)
        .mapToInt(row -> Arrays.stream(table[row]).sum()).toArray();
}
```

And:

```
private boolean oneIsSumOfTwoOthers(int[] sums) {
    return IntStream.range(0, sums.length)
        .anyMatch(s1 ->
            IntStream.range(0, sums.length)
            .filter(s2 -> s2 != s1)
            .anyMatch(s2 ->
                IntStream.range(0, sums.length)
                .filter(s3 -> s3 != s1 && s3 != s2)
                .anyMatch(s3 -> sums[s1] == sums[s2] + sums[s3])));
}
```